# what is the efficient way of creating app routes for post method having multiple args for same view

Tags: flask

i have dept like social, maths, science etc...
if social i will have 3 args 
if maths i have 2 args
if science i have 6 args

how can i write it dynamically with single app route and its a post method not GET so i can't use request.args.get neither i am not using WTForms too to capture the fields directly. i just need to create service where other application uses this API via POST call

how can i write as below in generic way:

```
@app.route("/name/<dept>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def Process():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        process()
```

As of now i am doing individual routes for each as below, is there any other efficient approach.

```
@app.route("/name/social/<part_time>/<pay>/<age>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@app.route("/name/maths/<part_time>/<pay>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
```

@app.route("/name/science//////", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])

#### As of now writing like this

```
@app.route("/name/social/<part_time>/<pay>/<age>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def processSocial():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        process()


@app.route("/name/maths/<part_time>/<pay>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def processMaths():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        process()



@app.route("/name/science/<part_time>/<pay>/<full_time>/<pay_full>/<age>/<designation>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def processScience():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        process()
```

expected is: have to write scenario in single approute
actual: writing different routes for each dept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple routes on single function, why do you want single route?.

```
@app.route("/name/<dept>/<part_time>/<pay>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@app.route("/name/<dept>/<part_time>/<pay>/<age>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@app.route("/name/<dept>/<part_time>/<pay>/<full_time>/<pay_full>/<age>/<designation>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def processDept(dept, 
                part_time, 
                pay, 
                age=None, 
                full_time=None, 
                pay_full=None, 
                designation=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        process()
```

Comment: so with single definition i need to have condition if dept == 'something': process() right ? but how handle if age is passed there, as age=None is set in def args

Comment: You are not using age in example so how could I know what do you want to do with it? Also in every example you call `process()` so I don't know if you need any condition.

Comment: okay.. what are the args we are mentioning we have to capture all those values depending on dept type...if dept is social i need to capture age whereas for maths i dont need age value and it will not exist also.